# Error creating bean with name - Spring Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I get the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'addArticleController' defined in file [C:\Users\...\controllers\AddArticleController.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.controllers.AddArticleController]: Constructor threw exception
```

This is my AddArticleConrtoller:

```
package com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.controllers;

import com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.models.*;
import com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.repo.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class AddArticleController {

    @Autowired
    ArticleCategoryRepository articleCategoryRepository;
    @Autowired
    MusicianRepository musicianRepository;
    @Autowired
    AlbumRepository albumRepository;
    @Autowired
    GenreRepository genreRepository;
    @Autowired
    CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @GetMapping("add_article")
    public String AddArticle(Model model) {
        List<ArticlesCategories> categories = articleCategoryRepository.findAll();
        List<Musicians> musicians = musicianRepository.findAll();
        List<Albums> albums = albumRepository.findAll();
        List<Genres> genres = genreRepository.findAll();
        List<Countries> countries = countryRepository.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("categories", categories);
        model.addAttribute("musicians", musicians);
        model.addAttribute("albums", albums);
        model.addAttribute("genres", genres);
        model.addAttribute("countries", countries);
        return "add_article";
    }
}
```

This is my full loggin out:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-22T01:08:53.550+03:00 ERROR 8624 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addArticleController' defined in file [C:\Users\dddry\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MusicJournal\MusicJournal\target\classes\com\MusicJournal\MusicJournal\controllers\AddArticleController.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.controllers.AddArticleController]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1314) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.MusicJournalApplication.main(MusicJournalApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.controllers.AddArticleController]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    MusicianRepository cannot be resolved to a type
    MusicianRepository cannot be resolved to a type

    at com.MusicJournal.MusicJournal.controllers.AddArticleController.<init>(AddArticleController.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:198) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 24 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've checked all I can and can't find a reason why this could be happening. I use such a development environment as Intellij IDEA and it does not give any errors at the stage of writing the code. And so, what could be the matter?

Comment: Based on your description, it seems there's an issue with the MusicianRepository class. Could you share that class? I'd also suggest ruling out IntelliJ Idea to ensure it's not a compilation problem on their end. Are you using Maven or Gradle?